# Storing the result of .dvalloc to a variable

Tags: windbg, virtual-memory

Is it possible to store the result of `.dvalloc` to a variable?

I mean the start address of allocated memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's easily possible in a single command, so all options are kind of nasty:

#### Store it manually

Pro: easy to understand. Use copy/paste (right click to copy, right click to paste BTW)

```
0:000> .dvalloc 100000
Allocated 100000 bytes starting at 00000000`00290000
0:000> r $t9 = 00000000`00290000
0:000> ? $t9
Evaluate expression: 2686976 = 00000000`00290000
```

#### Use a WinDbg script

Pro: no typos. Nice to use e.g. from a `.cmdtree` if you just need some memory once.

```
0:000> .foreach /pS 5 (addr {.dvalloc 100000}) {r $t8=${addr}}
0:000> ? $t8
Evaluate expression: 6881280 = 00000000`00690000
```

Instead of a register you could also define an alias

```
0:000> as /c memory .foreach /pS 5 (addr {.dvalloc 100000}) {.echo ${addr}}
0:000> ? memory
Evaluate expression: 12124160 = 00000000`00b90000
```

#### Store the address first, then use it in .dvalloc

Downside of this approach: you need to know if the address is unused.

```
0:000> r $t7=01000000; .dvalloc /b $t7 100000
Allocated 100000 bytes starting at 00000000`01000000
0:000> ? $t7
Evaluate expression: 16777216 = 00000000`01000000
```