# Windbg/cdb - Replace a slow conditional breakpoint with an in memory patch (32-bit)

Tags: windbg, breakpoints, monkeypatching, cdb

Using cdb, I have following conditional breakpoint

```
bp 004bf9f8 ".if (@eax = 0) {.echotime;.echo Breakpoint 004bf9f8;r};gc"
```

As this is to investigate an intermittent issue, it has to stay attached for quite some time but **the conditional breakpoint slows down** the overall performance of the application far more than I can afford.

- Anyone any idea how to optimize the conditional breakpoint? All it does is checking `eax=0`. I have read [some](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/501675/Whyplusareplusconditionalplusbreakpointsplussoplus) [posts](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/25a2fbe7-982f-4077-af69-1f8be20518e6/conditional-breakpoints-strangely-slow-in-loop?forum=vsdebug) [explaining](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/2b8wb5/why_is_it_that_conditional_breakpoints_are_so/) why conditional breakpoints slow down so much and those make perfect sense so I assume this is a dead end.
- I can pretty much do what I want with the in memory image. Would it be possible to patch some instructions as to insert something like `if eax = 0 { <whatever>}` so I could add an **unconditional** breakpoint on `<whatever>`?

**Edit**

from the comments, the plan of action is to script as follows

`.dvalloc <bytes>` and [store the result in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39559332/52598) called *patch*

```
a 004bfa08 JMP patch
a patch MOV eax,esi
a patch+x CMP eax,0
a patch+y JNE 004bfa0a
a patch+z JMP 004bfa0a
```

and now I should be able to add an unconditional breakpoint on `patch+z` to dump the information I need without halting the application.

```
bp patch+z ".echotime;.echo Breakpoint patch+z;~.;r;!dpx;gc"
```

**Edit 2**

Following POC works in a live debugging session but this still has to be converted to a script that doesn't halt the application, waiting for keypresses or anything.

**Commands executed**

```
.dvalloc 1000

a 004bfa00
JMP 0x0c570000
NOP

a 0xc570000
mov edi,edx
mov esi,eax
mov ebp,edi
cmp eax,0
jne 0x004bfa06
jmp 0x004bfa06

bp 0c570011 ".echo Hello World"
```

**Commands executed including output/context**

```
0:010> .dvalloc 1000
Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 0c570000

0:010> u 004bf9f8 LD
application+0xbf9f8:
004bf9f8 53              push    ebx
004bf9f9 56              push    esi
004bf9fa 57              push    edi
004bf9fb 55              push    ebp
004bf9fc 51              push    ecx
004bf9fd 890c24          mov     dword ptr [esp],ecx
004bfa00 8bfa            mov     edi,edx |
004bfa02 8bf0            mov     esi,eax |-> these get overwritten so repeat in patch
004bfa04 8bef            mov     ebp,edi |
004bfa06 8bd5            mov     edx,ebp
004bfa08 8bc6            mov     eax,esi
004bfa0a e8e5feffff      call    application+0xbf8f4 (004bf8f4)

0:010> a 004bfa00
JMP 0x0c570000
NOP

0:010> u 004bf9f8 LD
application+0xbf9f8:
004bf9f8 53              push    ebx
004bf9f9 56              push    esi
004bf9fa 57              push    edi
004bf9fb 55              push    ebp
004bf9fc 51              push    ecx
004bf9fd 890c24          mov     dword ptr [esp],ecx
004bfa00 e9fb050b0c      jmp     0c570000
004bfa05 90              nop
004bfa06 8bd5            mov     edx,ebp
004bfa08 8bc6            mov     eax,esi
004bfa0a e8e5feffff      call    application+0xbf8f4 (004bf8f4)

0:010> a 0xc570000
0c570000 mov edi,edx
mov edi,edx
0c570002 mov esi,eax
mov esi,eax
0c570004 mov ebp,edi
mov ebp,edi
0c570006 cmp eax,0
cmp eax,0
0c57000b jne 0x004bfa06
jne 0x004bfa06
0c570011 jmp 0x004bfa06
jmp 0x004bfa06
0c570016 

0:010> u 0x0c570000 L6
0c570000 8bfa            mov     edi,edx
0c570002 8bf0            mov     esi,eax
0c570004 8bef            mov     ebp,edi
0c570006 3d00000000      cmp     eax,0
0c57000b 0f85f5f9f4f3    jne     application+0xbfa06 (004bfa06)
0c570011 e9f0f9f4f3      jmp     application+0xbfa06 (004bfa06)

0:010> bp 0c570011 ".echo Hello World"
```

**Edit 3**

manually patching 7 running executables was successful but depending on the address returned by `.dvalloc`, the assembled `JMP` instruction contains a different instruction. I assumed it would be as simple as subtracting the address we jump to from the address obtained from `.dvalloc` but that does not seem to be the case.

```
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   .dvalloc+0x11 |a jmp 004bfa06 |opcode |cd       |LE
   --------------|---------------|-------|---------|------------
1. 00df0011      |e9f0f96cff     |e9     |f0f96cff |ff 6c f9 f0
2. 00e30011      |e9f0f968ff     |e9     |f0f968ff |ff 68 f9 f0
3. 00f00011      |e9f0f95bff     |e9     |f0f95bff |ff 5b f9 f0
4. 00ff0011      |e9f0f94cff     |e9     |f0f94cff |ff 4c f9 f0
5. 093a0011      |e9f0f911f7     |e9     |f0f911f7 |f7 11 f9 f0
6. 0c570011      |e9f0f9f4f3     |e9     |f0f9f4f3 |f3 f4 f9 f0
7. 0ce70011      |e9f0f964f3     |e9     |f0f964f3 |f3 64 f9 f0
   -------------------------------------------------------------
```

The first `f` is a sign bit perhaps?

**Edit 4**

The calculation is straightforward after all, took me long enough though. The first `f` indeed is the sign.

- Take the address to jump to. In my case `004bfa06`
- Subtract the end of the memory location of the `jmp 004bfa06` instruction. In my case, that is always `.dvalloc+0x16` (`.dvalloc+0x11` is the start of the instruction)

Applied to my last attempt (7), that gives

```
004fba01 - 0ce70016 = f3 64 f9 f0. 
The instruction to edit the memory at 0ce70011 then becomes e9f0f964f3.
```

---

Following is the function prologue where I am setting the breakpoint. The instruction at `004bfa08 (MOV param_1,ESI)` is redundant because of the previous instruction at `004bfa02 (MOV ESI,param_1)` so that might be usefull but I lack the knowledge on how to proceed from here.

```
                     **************************************************************
                     *                          FUNCTION                          *
                     **************************************************************
                     int * __register FUN_004bf9f8(int param_1, int param_2, 
     int *             EAX:4          <RETURN>
     int               EAX:4          param_1
     int               EDX:4          param_2
     int               ECX:4          param_3
     undefined4        Stack[-0x14]:4 local_14

004bf9f8 53              PUSH       EBX
004bf9f9 56              PUSH       ESI
004bf9fa 57              PUSH       EDI
004bf9fb 55              PUSH       EBP
004bf9fc 51              PUSH       param_3
004bf9fd 89 0c 24        MOV        dword ptr [ESP]=>local_14,param_3
004bfa00 8b fa           MOV        EDI,param_2
004bfa02 8b f0           MOV        ESI,param_1
004bfa04 8b ef           MOV        EBP,EDI
004bfa06 8b d5           MOV        param_2,EBP
004bfa08 8b c6           MOV        param_1,ESI
004bfa0a e8 e5 fe        CALL       FUN_004bf8f4
         ff ff
004bfa0f 8b d8           MOV        EBX,param_1
```

Comment: are you going to run this in cdb/windbg then just do a .dvalloc get some soace and assembke a detour  x64 assembly in windbg wont work assembke with some external tool like capstone and efit the btes in place using eb command

Comment: @blabb - I understand the gist of it but I'll have to catch up on using capstone *(this is a 32-bit program btw, not that it matters much)*. Where would you start the detour? Does it matter as long as I repeat the instructions in the detour that I replace calling the detour?

Comment: @blabb - ... and should you happen to have an example using cdb, that would be awesome.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - I have no doubt blabb is right. To me, this *is* also fun but it's a beyond what I'm currently comfortable with. I didn't know `.dvalloc` and I didn't now `a` to begin with. Playing with `a` right now.The Windbg help on `a` is lacking any examples so I assume I'll have to either find the opcodes in the Intel manuel or use a tool to aid me in the conversion. All new to me... very exciting ;). I assume Ghidra, IDA, capstone can do. I *have* done it using metasploit but the right name doesn't spring to mind... So much to learn, so little time.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - ok, this works `a <someaddress>;mov ecx,1;<enter>;u <someaddress>` but that leaves me wondering if this can be scripted?

Comment: i believe i have an answer here or in re i cant access pc hate typing in mobile will do an answer asap

Comment: if it is 32 bit you can use a  .dvalloc 0x1000  a result cmp eax 0 jne back to detour after restoring danaged bytes and executing else int 3 it will break when eax is 0 just assemble jmp const step back

Comment: @blabb - testing on a dumpfile using Windbg and it looks like whatever I do , I have to <enter> when using `a`. Do you know offhand if the command can be scripted?

Comment: I have edited the question with a plan of action.

Comment: @Thomas - sorry, this is 32-bit. I have just ended a poc in a live debugging session. I am going to add that to the question because that's still a long way from a working script *(that doesn't interrupt anything)*

Comment: @Thomas - I've added the commands to the question. Really exiting to see this working in a live debug session. Scripting this is another big hurdle though. If the `a` command isn't scriptable and now that I actually have the opcodes, maybe an alternative would be to just edit the memory returned by `.dvalloc`  with an `e*` variant

Comment: @ThomasWeller - From the *Commands executed including output/context* in the question, this is *(space separated)* essentially what should be put at the address returned from `.dvalloc`: `8bfa 8bf0 8bef 3d00000000 0f85f5f9f4f3 e9f0f9f4f3`. With your answer in getting the result from `.dvalloc` and an `e*` command, this might just work.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - I can't for the life of me figure out how `a <.dvalloc> jmp 0x004bfa06` gets translated to an instruction. The `e9` is the `JMP` opcode but the instruction following the opcode is, I assume, a relative address to `0x004bfa06`. I fail to see the logic as in how that address gets calculated.  I have edited the question to add a table where I manually have patched 7 running executables but if I can't figureout how to calculate the instruction, I can't script it. Did you have any luck?

Comment: Strike that, the LE dword is signed.The formula seems to be `004fba06 - (.dvalloc+0x16)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding Another Answer

source we are going to use compiled with in vs2017 community as x64
our task is to break only when eax = 0x1337 without any conditional bps

```
cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /EHsc /Od /nologo  patch.cpp /link /release /entry:main  /subsystem:windows
```

Source

```
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"kernel32.lib")
int count = 0;
int somefunc()
{
    return count++;
}
int main(void)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        somefunc();
        Sleep(2);
    }
}
```

the disassembly of function somefunc() is as follows

```
F:\src\deto>cdb -c "uf deto!somefunc;q" deto.exe | f:\git\usr\bin\awk.exe "/Reading/,/quit/"
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'uf deto!somefunc;q'
deto!somefunc:
00000001`40001000 4883ec18        sub     rsp,18h
00000001`40001004 8b05f61f0000    mov     eax,dword ptr [deto!count (00000001`40003000)]
00000001`4000100a 890424          mov     dword ptr [rsp],eax
00000001`4000100d 8b05ed1f0000    mov     eax,dword ptr [deto!count (00000001`40003000)]
00000001`40001013 ffc0            inc     eax
00000001`40001015 8905e51f0000    mov     dword ptr [deto!count (00000001`40003000)],eax
00000001`4000101b 8b0424          mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp]
00000001`4000101e 4883c418        add     rsp,18h
00000001`40001022 c3              ret
quit:
```

I am going to edit bytes in three places using this JavaScript

```
function log(a)
{
    host.diagnostics.debugLog( a + '\n');
}

function exec (cmdstr)
{
    return host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand(cmdstr);
}

function patch()
{
log("hi")
exec(".dvalloc /b 0x200000000 1000")
exec("eb 0x14000100a 0x49 0xbf 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x41 0xff 0xe7")
exec("eb 0x200000000 0x3d 0x37 0x13 0x0 0x0 0x49 0xbf 0x0 0x8 0x0 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x74 0x25 0x36 0x89 0x4 0x24 0xa1 0x0 0x30 0x0 0x40 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0xff 0xc0 0xa3 0x0 0x30 0x0 0x40 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x49 0xbf 0x1b 0x10 0x0 0x40 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x41 0xff 0xe7 0x41 0xff 0xe7")
exec("eb 0x200000800 0xcc")
}
```

the bytes to patch were taken from this python script

```
from keystone import *
print ("assemble at 0x14000100a\n")
CODE = b"mov r15,0x200000000;jmp r15"
ks = Ks(KS_ARCH_X86,KS_MODE_64)
encoding,count = ks.asm(CODE)
for i in encoding:
    print(hex(i),end = " ")
print("\n")
print ("Assemble at 0x200000000\n")
CODE = b"cmp eax,0x1337;\
        mov r15,0x200000800;\
        je here;\
        mov dword ptr ss:[rsp],eax;\
        mov eax,dword ptr ds:[0x140003000];\
        inc eax;\
        mov dword ptr ds:[0x140003000],eax;\
        mov r15, 0x14000101b;\
        jmp r15;\
        here:;\
        jmp r15;"
encoding,count = ks.asm(CODE)
for i in encoding:
    print(hex(i),end = " ")
print("\n")
print ("Assemble at 0x200000800 an int 3 aka 0xcc")
```

loaded the exe in windbg patched and executed to break in 0x200000800

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.17763.132 AMD64

ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ff9`b33f121c cc              int     3

0:000> .scriptload f:\wdscr\patch.js

JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'f:\wdscr\patch.js'

0:000> dx @$scriptContents.patch()
hi
@$scriptContents.patch()

0:000> uf deto!somefunc
Flow analysis was incomplete, some code may be missing
deto!somefunc [f:\src\deto\deto.cpp @ 5]:
    5 00000001`40001000 4883ec18        sub     rsp,18h
    6 00000001`40001004 8b05f61f0000    mov     eax,dword ptr [deto!count (00000001`40003000)]
    6 00000001`4000100a 49bf0000000002000000 mov r15,200000000h <<<<<<<<<<<
    6 00000001`40001014 41ffe7          jmp     r15 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

0:000> g
(3aec.405c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
00000002`00000800 cc              int     3 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
0:000> r eax
eax=1337
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably very unprofessional. Seriously. My x86 assembler knowledge is close to zero. I really like to see an answer of @blabb or someone else who really understands what he does. Anyway, here's what I've achieved using 32 Bit Notepad (`C:\Windows\SysWow64\notepad.exe`).

Address of new memory in $t8

```
0:007> ~0s
0:000> .foreach /pS 5 (addr {.dvalloc 100000}) {r $t8=${addr}}; ? $t8
Evaluate expression: 179699712 = 0ab60000
```

Address of method to be patched in $t7

```
0:000> .foreach /pS 3 (addr {.frame 2}) {r $t7=${addr}}; ? $t7
0:000> .writemem winmain.mem $t7 L200
0:000> u $t7 L7
notepad!WinMain+0x1a3:
007ec4a6 85c0            test    eax,eax
007ec4a8 0f8567ffffff    jne     notepad!WinMain+0x112 (007ec415)
007ec4ae 8d442438        lea     eax,[esp+38h]
007ec4b2 50              push    eax
007ec4b3 6a00            push    0
007ec4b5 ff3500288000    push    dword ptr [notepad!szFileName (00802800)]
007ec4bb ff150c328000    call    dword ptr [notepad!_imp__GetFileAttributesExW (0080320c)]
```

Patch: jump to new memory. Pad this with NOPs until we end up on the next statement

```
0:000> eb $t7+0 50 B8
0:000> ed $t7+2 $t8+20
0:000> eb $t7+6 FF E0 58 90 90 90 
0:000> u $t7 L7
notepad!WinMain+0x1a3:
007ec4a6 50              push    eax            // because we need it for the jump
007ec4a7 b80000b60a      mov     eax,0AB60000h
007ec4ac ffe0            jmp     eax
007ec4ae 58              pop     eax
007ec4af 90              nop
007ec4b0 90              nop
007ec4b1 90              nop
```

Prepare destination: add hello world code

```
0:000> eu $t8 "Hello world!"
0:000> eb $t8+20 B8 00 00 00 00 50 B8
0:000> ed $t8+27 $t8
0:000> eb $t8+2b 50 50 B8 00 00 00 00 50 B8
0:000> ed $t8+34 USER32!MessageBoxW
0:000> eb $t8+38 FF D0 58 58 58 58 58

0:000> u $t8+20 LE
0ab60020 b800000000      mov     eax,0           // MB_OK
0ab60025 50              push    eax             
0ab60026 b80000b60a      mov     eax,0AB60000h   // "Hello world!"
0ab6002b 50              push    eax             // Text
0ab6002c 50              push    eax             // Caption
0ab6002d b800000000      mov     eax,0           // Desktop HWND
0ab60032 50              push    eax
0ab60033 b87013b077      mov     eax,offset USER32!MessageBoxW (77b01370)
0ab60038 ffd0            call    eax
0ab6003a 58              pop     eax  // Desktop HWND
0ab6003b 58              pop     eax  // Caption
0ab6003c 58              pop     eax  // Text
0ab6003d 58              pop     eax  // MB_OK
0ab6003e 58              pop     eax  // EAX which was rescued before jumping here
```

Add code from WinMain:

```
0:000> .readmem winmain.mem $t8+3f L200
Reading 200 bytes.

0:000> u $t8+3f L3
0ab6003f 85c0            test    eax,eax
0ab60041 0f8567ffffff    jne     0ab5ffae
0ab60047 8d442438        lea     eax,[esp+38h]
```

0F85 is a relative JNE.

```
007ec4a8 0f8567ffffff    jne     notepad!WinMain+0x112 (007ec415)
0:000> ? dwo($t8+43)
Evaluate expression: -153 = ffffff67
```

Let's fix that:

```
0:000> ed $t8+43 ($t7+2)-($t8+41)+dwo($t8+43)
0:000> u $t8+3f L3
0ab6003f 85c0            test    eax,eax
0ab60041 0f85cec3c8f5    jne     notepad!WinMain+0x112 (007ec415)
0ab60047 8d442438        lea     eax,[esp+38h]
```

And go back

```
0:000> eb $t8+4b 50 B8
0:000> ed $t8+4d $t7+8
0:000> eb $t8+51 ff e0
0:000> u $t8+4b L3
0ab6004b 50              push    eax  // Because we need it for the jump
0ab6004c b8aec47e00      mov     eax,offset notepad!WinMain+0x1ab (007ec4ae)
0ab60051 ffe0            jmp     eax
```

Let's break to see it happen

```
0:000> bp $t8+20
0:000> bp $t7
0:000> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  0aea0020     0001 (0001)  0:**** 
     1 e Disable Clear  007ec4a6     0001 (0001)  0:**** notepad!WinMain+0x1a3

0:000> g
Breakpoint 1 hit
007ec4a6 50              push    eax
0:000> p
007ec4a7 b82000ea0a      mov     eax,0AEA0020h
0:000> p
007ec4ac ffe0            jmp     eax {0aea0020}
0:000> p
Breakpoint 0 hit
0aea0020 b800000000      mov     eax,0
0:000> g
Breakpoint 1 hit
007ec4a6 50              push    eax
0:000> bd 0
0:000> bd 1
```

[image: Hello world message displayed by Notepad]

After some message boxes, I get

```
STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN encountered
(2f28.4008): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
```

and I don't really know why.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I really could use an example. I'll let you know the end result.

Answer (score 1):

E9 opcode can jump only +- 2GB so it is kinda crippled in x64
you may need to load a  scratch register and jump there

.dvalloc has a switch /b with which you can specify an address so you don't have to deal with .parsing .dvalloc

x64 assemble command wont work in windbg you may need an external tool like keystone

[keystone](https://github.com/keystone-engine/keystone/releases/) is c but python bindings are available ([installable from msi](https://github.com/keystone-engine/keystone/releases/download/0.9.1/keystone-0.9.1-python-win64.msi) )

assuming you have python and keystone

```
from keystone import *
CODE = b"mov r15,0x200000000;jmp r15"
ks = Ks(KS_ARCH_X86,KS_MODE_64)
encoding,count = ks.asm(CODE)
for i in encoding:
    print(hex(i),end = " ")
print("\n")
```

will output these 12 bytes (you will be damaging 12 bytes so you need to save them)

0x49 0xbf 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x41 0xff 0xe7

now this is the complete disassembly of an arbitrary function which I am detouring

```
0:000> uf .
deto!somefunc [f:\src\deto\deto.cpp @ 5]:
    5 00000001`40001000 4883ec18        sub     rsp,18h
    6 00000001`40001004 8b05f61f0000    mov     eax,dword ptr [deto!count (00000001`40003000)]
    6 00000001`4000100a 890424          mov     dword ptr [rsp],eax
    6 00000001`4000100d 8b05ed1f0000    mov     eax,dword ptr [deto!count (00000001`40003000)]
    6 00000001`40001013 ffc0            inc     eax
    6 00000001`40001015 8905e51f0000    mov     dword ptr [deto!count (00000001`40003000)],eax
    6 00000001`4000101b 8b0424          mov     eax,dword ptr [rsp]
    7 00000001`4000101e 4883c418        add     rsp,18h
    7 00000001`40001022 c3              ret
```

I am detouring at address 14000100a 
I have allocated 0x1000 sized memory at 0x200000000 using .dvalloc and redisassembling again

```
0:000> .dvalloc /b 200000000 1000
Allocated 1000 bytes starting at 00000002`00000000
0:000> eb 14000100a 0x49 0xbf 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x41 0xff 0xe7
0:000> uf .
Flow analysis was incomplete, some code may be missing
deto!somefunc [f:\src\deto\deto.cpp @ 5]:
    5 00000001`40001000 4883ec18        sub     rsp,18h
    6 00000001`40001004 8b05f61f0000    mov     eax,dword ptr [deto!count (00000001`40003000)]
    6 00000001`4000100a 49bf0000000002000000 mov r15,200000000h
    6 00000001`40001014 41ffe7          jmp     r15
```

assemble your logic in 0x200000000 restore damaged bytes and return back to flow 
if the return address is in middle of an instruction you may need to use a proper address

for the code shown above you may have to return back to 14000101b as damaging just 12 bytes will be damaging the first byte at instruction 140001015

Comment: Still digesting most of it, yet following remarks: as I'm working with 32-bit, E9 will not be an issue I assume?. How wan I be sure that a range of memory I try to allocate with .dvalloc will actually be availble? Not having to parse makes things easier but more brittle to no?

Comment: e9 is ok in 32 bit also a (assemble command is ok in 32 bit but was behaving erratically iirc )  you can always modify the script to take an argument instead of blindly hardcoding an address like 0x200000000  like .dvalloc /b someaddr if success dx @$scriptcontents.patch(result) and use host.parseInt64() to evaluate and stringify inside javascript

Answer (score 1):

**Acknowledgment**

A BIG shout out to blabb and Thomas for the help, patience and examples[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61091302/52598)[(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61089664/52598)[(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61090262/52598) they have provided. If anyone stumbles on this question and is helped by it, please give them your votes!

Specific to my situation, these were the manual actions needed to patch up the function at `0x004bf9f8` to jump to a newly created patch where I could test eax for nil and set an unconditional breakpoint.

**Manual actions**

This worked but it's still cumbersome. The parent application spawns children of the application I needed to patch so this required quite a bit of effort and a risk of mistyping or missing an application.

```
* Make a note of the address returned (pe. 0x00df0000)
.dvalloc 100

* Replace all <patch> by previous returned address. Copy/past following 3 lines (+enter)
a 004bfa00
JMP <patch>
NOP

* Copy/paste following 7 lines (+enter)
a <patch>
mov edi,edx
mov esi,eax
mov ebp,edi
cmp eax,0
jne 0x004bfa06
jmp 0x004bfa06

* Copy/paste following line 1 in cdb
bp <patch>+0x11 ".echo Breakpoint 004bf9f8 Nil Pointer Unconditional Check;r!dpx};gc"

* Verify
u 004bf9f8 LD
u <patch> LD
```

**Scripting of the manual actions**

Again, I wouldn't have know where to begin without the help provided. 
Following issues with trying to script the manual actions

- The `a` command in Windbg/cdb can't be used in a script <sub>(disclaimer: pretty sure of it)</sub>
- Without the `a` command, I had to resort to editing memory and look up the required opcodes
- Calculating relative jumps

**Script with minimal comment**

```
* Make note of returned address and store in $t8
.foreach /pS 5 (patch {.dvalloc 100}) {r $t8=${patch}}; ? $t8

* Patch the function to jump to $t8
r $t9=$t8-(0x004bfa00+0x05)
eb 0x004bfa00 e9
ed 0x004bfa01 $t9
eb 0x004bfa05 90

* Create the patch at $t8
ew $t8+0x00 fa8b
ew $t8+0x02 f08b
ew $t8+0x04 ef8b
eb $t8+0x06 3d
ed $t8+0x07 00000000
r $t9=0x004bfa06-($t8+0x11)
ew $t8+0x0b 850f
ed $t8+0x0d $t9
r $t9=0x004bfa06-($t8+0x16)
eb $t8+0x11 e9
ed $t8+0x12 $t9

* Set the unconditional breakpoint
bp $t8 ".echo Breakpoint 004bf9f8 Nil Pointer Unconditional Check;r;!dpx};gc"

* Verify
u 004bf9f8 LD
u $t8 LD
```

**Script with a bit excessive comment**

```
***** Allocate 100 bytes of memory to hold our patch
*     Remember the start adress in the $t8 pseudo register
.foreach /pS 5 (patch {.dvalloc 100}) {r $t8=${patch}}; ? $t8

***** Patch the function to jump to $t8
*     Jump to our patch when entering function 0x004bf948 to test for nil pointer
* 1 0x004bfa00 e9<offset>      jmp     <patch> ($t8 LE)
* 2 0x004bfa05 90              nop

        ***** 1 0x004bfa00 e9<offset> jmp <patch> ($t8 LE)
        * r $t9   the size of the jump from 0x004bfa00+0x05 to $t8
        * eb      e9 is the opcode for JMP
        * ed      append with offset where to jump to
        r $t9=$t8-(0x004bfa00+0x05)
        eb 0x004bfa00 e9
        ed 0x004bfa01 $t9

        ***** 2 0x004bfa05 90 nop
        * eb      90 is the opcode for NOP
        eb 0x004bfa05 90

***** Create the patch at $t8
*     Repeat the replaced code at 0x004bfa00 used to jump to our new address
*     Add a compare with nil
*     Jump back to where we left off (0x004bfa06)
* 1 0x00000000 8bfa            mov     edi,edx
* 2 0x00000002 8bf0            mov     esi,eax
* 3 0x00000004 8bef            mov     ebp,edi
* 4 0x00000006 3d00000000      cmp     eax,0
* 5 0x0000000b 0f85<offset>    jne     app+0xbfa06 (004bfa06)
* 6 0x00000011 e9<offset>      jmp     app+0xbfa06 (004bfa06)

        ***** 1 0x0000000 mov edi,edx
        * ew      8b is the opcode for MOV
        *         fa is the opcode for ebp,edi
        ew $t8+0x00 fa8b

        ***** 2 0x0000002 mov esi,eax
        * ew      8b is the opcode for MOV
        *         f0 is the opcode for esi,eax
        ew $t8+0x02 f08b

        ***** 3 0x0000004 mov ebp,edi
        * ew      8b is the opcode for MOV
        *         ef is the opcode for ebp,edi
        ew $t8+0x04 ef8b

        ***** 4 0x0000006 cmp eax,0
        * eb      3d is the opcode for JNE
        * ed      append with what to compare with
        eb $t8+0x06 3d
        ed $t8+0x07 00000000

        ***** 5 0x000000b jne app+0xbfa06 (004bfa06)
        * r $t9   the size of the jump from $t8+11 to 0x004bfa06
        * ew      0f 85 is the opcode for JNE
        * ed      append with offset where to jump to
        r $t9=0x004bfa06-($t8+0x11)
        ew $t8+0x0b 850f
        ed $t8+0x0d $t9

        ***** 6 jmp app+0xbfa06 (004bfa06)
        * r $t9   the size of the jump from $t8+16 to 0x004bfa06
        * eb      e9 is the opcode for JMP
        * ed      append with offset where to jump to
        r $t9=0x004bfa06-($t8+0x16)
        eb $t8+0x11 e9
        ed $t8+0x12 $t9

***** Conditional Breakpoint/Log on address $t8
bp $t8+0x11 ".echo Breakpoint 004bf9f8 Nil Pointer Unconditional Check;r;!dpx};gc"

***** Verify
u 004bf9f8 LD
u $t8 LD
```